# Handle a response code in test without polluting ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, error-handling

My problem is that we're receiving mysterious 504 errors in SolanoCI, and I'm trying to find a clean way to handle them only in the test environment without adding test-specific code to our ApplicationController.

I've tried stubbing a default handler via the test setup like so:

```
allow(ApplicationController).to receive(:timeout).and_return { 
  #do a bunch of stuff to try to pull out request information
}
```

but I'm finding that it's lacking some important information that's accessible, like the original request url and any stacktrace information.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: 504 usually indicates that there's some network connectivity issues (Gateway Timeout).  If this is happening only in your test environment, I would discourage writing code to address what is ostensibly an environmental network configuration issue.  It may be more productive to talk with whomever manages the network and figure out if there's been any weird connectivity blips to that particular server over the last few days.

Comment: As stated in the question, it's run on SolanoCI.  Since all requests should be mocked or internal in a CI environment, they're our responsibility to handle.  Normally, I'd agree with you, but since this is a test-specific issue it's dubious that these are legitimate 504s.

Comment: Can't you use something like VCR to just record the expected responses?

Comment: @ruby_newbie We're running VCR.  These are happening even with VCR and webmock handling all external requests.  That's why we need logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way for you in this situation would be to ask Solano to run a [debugging session](http://docs.solanolabs.com/Beta/interactive-debug-console/) on their box for you (they give you ssh access to their server, so you may run tests yourself).

This is a real time saver in a black box situations like this. You may run tests multiple times and use all sorts of debugging tools there. You may have to install them first, since Solano tries not to install extra tools from your Gemfile (such as pry) to minimize test's running time.

Just write them via a contact form and they will give you an access. Don't forget to stop that session after you've done with it, since the time it runs is deducted from worker hours in your plan.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**: It seems [Anonymous controller](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller) feature is perfect for your case:

> Use the `controller` method to define an anonymous controller that will
>   inherit from the described class. This is useful for specifying
>   behavior like global error handling.

So, you can do something like this:

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationController, :type => :controller do
  controller(ApplicationController) do

    rescue_from Timeout::Error, :with => :log_timeout

    def log_timeout(error)
      # log error as you wish
    end
  end

  describe "handling timeout exceptions" do
    it "writes some logs" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_https_status(504)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion, and thank you for that.  However, we've actually already done this.  Since 504 errors aren't going to be necessarily in one part of the code, we still need a way to catch and debug them there.

Comment: Please, clarify, what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to stub ApplicationController so it throws Timeout::Error and check how your code catches that? Or add some wrapper to ApplicationController and debug where do your real timeout errors come from?

Comment: I want to be able to log this for a test only issue without having to pollute my ApplicationController.  Since we can't blackbox this and it's intermittent, I'd like to put it in our merged master without having to include it in the ApplicationController and running it on potentially legitimate 504s.

Comment: @JoshBurgess Please, take a look, I've updated my answer.